# Woocommerce - Remover botão de compra

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estou com o seguinte problema, na verdade são 2 situações:

**1° situação:**
Preciso Remover botão "comprar" quando o produto não possuir preço cadastrado.

Estou fazendo uma loja com o woocommerce onde existem diversos produtos e cadastrei os mesmos como produtos variaveis, porém alguns deles não tem preço cadastrado (pois ainda não temos os valores destes). Incluí um botão para redirecionar o cliente para área de contato e assim podermos negociar a encomenda. Porém, necessito remover a opção de compra deste campo quando o produto estiver com valor zerado.
[image: primeira situacao]
**2° Situação**
Quando o produto tem valor cadastrado e não tem estoque, ele se apresenta desta forma: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu preciso que ele apareça com a mesma mensagem da 1° situação e também sem o botão de compra.
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? 
Obrigado!
Link para produto:

Woocommerce versão 3.2.5
Wordpress versão 4.9.1

Comment: Tenta esse: `<style>button.single_add_to_cart_button{display: none !important;}</style>`

Comment: Esse deu certo, o botão desapareceu

Comment: Tinha um erro num código que mandei.. tenta esse aqui `<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("button.single_add_to_cart_button").remove();});</script>`

Comment: Nada também cara

Comment: Eu baixei um site com Woocommerce para testar e funcionou aqui. Mas tem um artigo que dá alguma dica de como fazer isso usando o próprio recurso do plugin: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-remove-hide-or-disable-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce/

Comment: Então, é que na verdade eu tenho 2 situações... Tenho que fazer com que nao apareça o botão quando o produto é variavel e está sem valor e também quando o produto tem valor, é variavel e não tem estoque. são 2 situações distintas

Comment: Você consegue criar alguma variável no PHP que detecta isso? Tipo, `$esconder_botão = true;` se o produto não tem preço

Comment: Então, eu acho que é possível, porém eu não tenho expertise para criar essa variável e fazer ela funcionar, rs. esse é o problema...

Comment: Esse site está em servidor online ou é local?

Comment: está online sim
http://gagamilano.com.br/produto/manuale-48mm-pdv/
veja o ultimo produto da seleção, ele tem preço cadastrado e está selecionado como fora de estoque
este é o mesmo exemplo que cito na questão aqui do stackoverflow

A ideia é ele aparecer da mesma forma que a imagem 1, porém sem o botão de compra também..